# Creating Admin Panel Rails from scratch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, admin, edit

I would like to create an admin section for rails. I have progress a little. But I would like to ask a question.

Imagine you have controllers such as;

```
Users_controller
Boats_controller
Cars_controller
etc etc
```

For those controller you have actions such as `EDIT, DESTROY, UPDATE.` 
I am not sure if this is logical;

I will use `index` action in the `admin_controller` to show all users in the database with an EDIT link.

When Admin clicks to EDIT link, it directs him to `User_controller EDIT` action as an url of `localhost/User/:id/edit`. Is this way is ok or not?

Comment: I suggest you create custom action, something like `edit_user` and do it there

Comment: admin can edit any user's information?

Comment: It is based on your application flow,

if you are going to use ``users_controller`` for any other purpose then you should not send it to users_controller edit action, if your ``users_controller``  is not being used then you can use this ``user_controller`` to perform edit operation

Comment: why not use index action of users_controller?  and more permanent solution to this problem is to have CanCan to manage roles of the user as "super_admin", "admin","manager" and so on.